# Api Platform : order on an entity cascade

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

With Api Platform, we can order by association.

[Documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/default-order/) :

```
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

/**
 * @ApiResource(attributes={"order"={"author.username"}})
 */
class Book
{
    ...
```

But I want to order on an entity cascade.

For the example below I tested this with this error :

```
 * @ApiResource(
 *     attributes={
 *         "order"={"exercises.repetitions.id":"asc"}
 *     }
 * )
```

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 422 near 'id ASC, rests_a6.id': Error: Class App\Entity\TrainingSerieExercise has no field or association named repetitions.id

`TrainingSerie` entity :

```
 * @ApiResource(
       ...
 *     attributes={
 *         "order"={"exercises.repetitions.id":"asc"}
 *     }
 * )
 */
class TrainingSerie
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var TrainingSerieExercise[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="App\Entity\TrainingSerieExercise",
     *     mappedBy="serie",
     *     cascade={"persist"}
     * )
     * @Groups({
     *     "trainings_read",
     *     "training_series_read",
     *     "training_series_write",
     * })
     */
    private $exercises;

...
```

`TrainingSerieExercise` entity :

```
...
class TrainingSerieExercise
{
    ...
    /**
     * @var TrainingSerieRepetition[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="App\Entity\TrainingSerieExerciseRepetition",
     *     mappedBy="exercise",
     *     cascade={"persist"},
     * )
     * @Groups({
     *     "training_series_read",
     *     "training_series_write",
     *     "training_serie_exercices_write",
     * })
     */
    private $repetitions;
    ...
```

`TrainingSerieExerciseRepetition` entity :

```
class TrainingSerieExerciseRepetition
{
    ...
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Groups({
     *     "training_series_read",
     * })
     */
    private $id;
    ...
```

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. `$repetitions` is a collection, it can't have an individual id. It's not clear at all what exactly do you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Yes, `repetitions` is a collection (`TrainingSerieExerciseRepetition[]`), and each element of this collection contains two fields (`id` and `repetition`). I want the parent entity (`TrainingSerie`) to order this collection by `id` (but it could have been by `repetition`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this [Doctrine doc](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/ordered-associations.html#ordering-to-many-associations) this will order TrainingSerieExercise::$repetitions by id:

```
class TrainingSerieExercise
{
    ...
    /**
     * @var TrainingSerieRepetition[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="App\Entity\TrainingSerieExerciseRepetition",
     *     mappedBy="exercise",
     *     cascade={"persist"},
     * )
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "ASC"})
     * @Groups({
     *     "training_series_read",
     *     "training_series_write",
     *     "training_serie_exercices_write",
     * })
     */
    private $repetitions;
    ...
```